# Python: How to run a script1 from script2 and DUPLICATE script1's output (stdout, stderr) in script2 for logging (into a file)

Tags: python

I have two python scripts: script1.py and script2.py

I want to run script1 from script2 (os.system, subprocess.Popen, ..) and then log script1's output (stdout, stderr) to a file log.txt, while still seeing script1's and script2's outputs on my terminal (as I would see, without the logging feature), as the are printed on ..

N.B.: It essential that log.txt exactly reflects the output (stdout, stderr) i would get on screen/terminal, corresponding to script1's run.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

dOpP

Answer (score 1):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module (not `os.system`).  Send stdout and stderr to a pipe and capture them in local variables (using `communicate` probably).  Once you have them in local vars you can both print them and write them to a file (so you're probably most of the way there already).

Something like:

```
log = open("log.txt", "w+")
p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env', 'python', 'script1.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
print out,err
log.write(out)
log.write(err)
```

Comment: Hello guys,

Once more, thanks to every one who answered me (sorin, nick b., etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no function in python standard library that does this but you can use [`tendo.tee()`](https://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/blob/master/tendo/tee.py).

Comment: @dOpP I didn't had time to write a documentation for the library, but if it is needed file a bug, maybe this will motivate me to write the doc for it.